# sc qprivs blank priviliges

Tags: windows, privileges

When running the following command I receive this output:

> SERVICE_NAME: AdobeARMservice

```
    PRIVILEGES       :
```

> [SC] QueryServiceConfig2 SUCCESS

My question is what kind of privileges AdobeARMservice has? it seems none...but It can't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I'm not sure that the Adobe ARM service does require any privileges.  The local system token always includes the Administrators group, which is explicitly granted access to most files and registry entries.  Privileges are typically required for system tasks such as loading a device driver, viewing the security audit log, or changing the time zone.  The most common privilege required by services is probably "impersonate a client", but that isn't applicable in this case.  It might want "shut down the system", I suppose, so that it can initiate a reboot after installing an update.

As it happens, though, if no privileges list is configured, the service gets all privileges associated with the security principle, which in this case is most of them.

Quoting from [MSDN (SERVICE_REQUIRED_PRIVILEGES_INFO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):  "If you do not set the required privileges, the SCM uses all the privileges assigned by default to the process token."

I've just checked, and for a service which does not set the list of required privileges, `sc qprivs` does indeed display an empty list as shown in your question.  If I remember correctly, explicitly setting an empty list has the same effect.  If the service doesn't want any privileges, it will set a list with just one item, SeChangeNotifyPrivilege, which everyone always gets anyway.